# When was the last cavalry charge?

Tags: war, military, cavalry

When was the last instance of a unit of cavalry charging? I know that the Polish forces had units of cavalry during World War II and those were used against Nazi units but was there any later than that?

Edited notes: Got my original facts wrong. Polish cavalry did not charge tanks but did charge units of Nazi troops at Krojanty. That charge was successful but the battle was lost.  However, cavalry charges were used during the war but not as the popular myth has it. Source: [guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2011/apr/06/myth-of-polish-cavalry-charge), [historynet](http://www.historynet.com/polish-cavalry-charges-tanks.htm) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_cavalry#Cavalry_charges_and_propaganda).

Comment: Not sure if this question belongs here? http://www.google.com.au/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=last+cavalry+charge+of+the+war

Comment: If you downvote, please leave a comment as to how to improve the question. Thanks.

Comment: That down vote wasn't me, but I have raised a meta question on the suitability of the question. Feel free to come and discuss. http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/46/does-the-last-cavalry-charge-question-belong-on-the-site

Comment: I think "charge" might be slightly misleading in the title. Perhaps renaming it to "When was the last cavalry used?" Of course ignoring the recent "cavalries" that exist in the modern military by way of tanks or helos.

Comment: @GPierce helos would be more like "horse archers" than "cavalry" imo

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even in modern combat horses are still used.  There was a book written about US Special Forces soldiers in Afghanistan who relied heavily on horses in combat.  The book is called [Horse Soldiers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1416580514).

Comment: +1 - Nomads in Africa still use horses and camels in military actions and raids against farming villages.

Comment: Use of horses and cavalry charge are two different things. Does this book mention charges in particular?

Comment: @T.E.D. Any references for the use of camels or horses in Africa?I mainly heard of pick ups and motorbikes

Comment: @totalMongot - Shame you didn't ask this 10 years ago when it was fresh in my mind.

Comment: @T.E.D. Oh right sorry I did not see the year^^
Still, ten years ago the use of cavalry was marginal compared to pick ups

Comment: @totalMongot - I remember it being all over the news back then. Rather a lot has happened since though.

Answer (score 10):

There was a number of minor fight incidents, involving cavalry units during WW2, see [here](http://www.militaryphotos.net/forums/showthread.php?181091-Some-interesting-cavalry-charges-in-WW2) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalry#World_War_II). However cavalry was used as a mean of transportation, or as a mounted infantry.

The last significant battle where cavalry used as a separate combat arms seems to be battle of [Komarow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Komar%C3%B3w) in August 1920, during Polish-Soviet war.

Comment: This is incorrect. Perhaps this was the last use of cav as a separate combat arm, but the last charge was March 1, 1945 when the the 1st Warsaw Cavalry Brigade charged through German lines to return to their Soviet allies.

Comment: That incident could be the last cavalry charge indeed, but it was a minor episode (7 KIA and 10 WIA), and not a major event. More info in Polish: http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_Warszawska_Samodzielna_Brygada_Kawalerii#Dzia.C5.82ania_bojowe

Comment: Yep I agree it was minor, but still more recent than your example. The OP doesn't specify a minimum size.

Comment: Red Army definitely used cavalry at least to the end of WWII. Red Army included 19 army cavalry corpses and 7 guards cavalry corpses during WWII, each corps consisting of three divisions.

Comment: @Anixx: but do you have evidence they were used as such?

Comment: @Felix Goldberg of course. Cavalry was one of the major forces in WWII. There are numerous paintings and films about cavalry in WWII. This relates to all sides in WWII. Red Army cavalry attack in WWII: http://medveputa.net/gallery/vov-i-ww2-a15/kavaleriyskaya-ataka-2-y-ukrainskiy-front-1944-g-jpg-i601.jpg Polish cavalry, 1939: http://img404.imageshack.us/img404/1086/polishcavalryattack.jpg SS cavalry charge: http://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/c/3/75/137/75137384_large_kavaleristuy_Mertvoy_Golovuy.jpg

Comment: For example, a legendary attack by Red Cossack Cavalry near Kuschevka in 1942 which was memorized in many pieces of art: http://www.vpered-kr.ru/kuban-cossacks/kuban-motherland/379-feat-cossacks.html http://patrik1990.livejournal.com/137249.html?thread=352545

Comment: "Soviet cavalry under Moscow" by Krivinogov: http://foto.infan.ru/img/f/26/k/krivonogov2.jpg "Cossack attack" by Tumanov: http://www.vpered-kr.ru/images/stories/Raznoe/cossack-attack--tumanov.jpg "Attack under Kuschevks by Kuban Cossacks in 1942" by Zelimkhan: http://ic.pics.livejournal.com/patrik1990/29120467/117673/original.jpg Monument to Cossack Guards http://ic.pics.livejournal.com/patrik1990/29120467/117086/original.jpg

Comment: Cossacks at Victory parade: http://ot-a-do-ya.org/Images/Articles/Kazak/Cossacks_in_VOV/kazaki_na_parade_VOV.png http://foto.infan.ru/img/f/20/8/8268a91bb19a.jpg

Comment: Lev Dovator was a legendary Soviet cavalry general http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lev_Dovator There were numerous films and books http://eritern.com/books/3339-general-dovator.html about him.

Comment: Romanian cavalry http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/2712/83653351.157/0_8826c_4a6b1f61_L Italian cavalry: http://i.blog.fontanka.ru/photos/2012/04/580x380_UBZRxrQzt85c5O274H4y.jpg

Answer (score 2):

One of the last significant cavalry charges was the [Charge of the Savoia Cavalleria at Izbushensky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_of_the_Savoia_Cavalleria_at_Izbushensky) August 24, 1942 when the Italian [Reggimento "Savoia Cavalleria" (3°)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regiment_%22Savoia_Cavalleria%22_(3rd)) performed a charge against the [Soviet 812th Rifle Regiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/304th_Rifle_Division_(Soviet_Union)) near Избушенский (Izbushensky).

In the early morning, Italian scouts discovered Soviet troops preparing a surprise attack. With surprise spoiled, the Soviets attacked the encamped Italians. Colonel Alessandro, commanding the regiment, ordered a cavalry charge with saber and grenade as a last resort. 2nd squadron (100 horsemen) used a gorge to outflank the Soviets and began storming along the entrenched infantry line.

2nd squadron took heavy casualties. Rather than breaking, the Soviets would shelter in their holes until the cavalry passed, then get up to fire into their backs. Alessandro ordered 4th squadron to dismount and launch a frontal attack while 2nd squadron regrouped behind the Soviets for another charge. 3rd squadron then charged in the open taking awful casualties.

The regiment lost over 100 horses, but the charge relieved pressure and delayed the Soviets by 24 hours.

This was pointed out by The Armchair Historian in his video [*Times Italy WAS Effective in WWII*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3K1WsOyxjao), though I think his statement of 1050 Soviet casualties are overblown.

Answer (score 1):

While not military, but the police in Malmö, Sweden performed several cavalry charges in 2014.[Polisens kavallerichock får hård kritik](http://www.dn.se/arkiv/nyheter/polisens-kavallerichock-far-hard-kritik/) [video](https://youtu.be/OB0-MXNPUIU)

Comment: The Dutch police used horses last week to control riots. Police use of horses is somewhat different from military use.

Comment: @Jos Yes, using horses for crowd control is standard procedure. A cavalry charge isn't. https://youtu.be/OB0-MXNPUIU