# What happened to the cavalry corps of Simon Boudienny?

Tags: world-war-two, russia, cavalry

According to this [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/36342/what-tactical-situations-made-the-use-of-traditional-horse-cavalry-effective-in/53079#53079), there was a campaign led by the Russians in Ukraine where they engaged a cavalry unit. I imagine it was in 1941, and according to Wikipedia research, it might be the cavalry corps of Simon Boudienny.

Do you have details on his action? Why did he fail in repelling the advancing Germans, and was it because of lack of efficiency of the cavalry tactics?

Comment: Boudienny was a marshal in 1941 and was very unlikely to command a corps. As far as I know, in 1941 he was the commander of the South-Western "direction" (направления in Russian), so he was the commander of all corps, armies, fronts etc. in the South-West. Boudienny was the commander of the 1st "Horse Army" (Конной армии in Russian) in the Russian civil war and gained certain fame in that role. So you might be confusing 1941 and 1920

Comment: Exact, I was wrong by stating that Boudienny was leading this cav corps. Still, cav corps operate against the forces of Guderian and other German divisions when Simon Boudienny tried to oppose to the outflanking of Kiev

Comment: During the Second World War the cavalry corps were used primarily as components of the Cavalry Mechanized Groups that were inserted into the breakthrough sector of the Front following an offensive, paired with either a tank corps or a mechanized corps, providing additional mobile infantry component that could escort tanks and support them against enemy anti-tank defences (wikipedia)

Comment: Any new hindsights about the battle, how Boudienny behaves?